# Sonarqube failed to create user cache

Tags: docker, unix, sonarqube, sonarscanner

I'm creating a Sonarqube environment with Docker, but when I run the scanner, an error occurred.

I run the scanner directly into the container :

```
PS C:\docker\sonarqube\projects\test> docker exec -it sonarqube /bin/bash
```

```
sonarqube@05399e4fa8a6:/home/projects/test$ sonar-scanner
```

> INFO: Scanner configuration file: /usr/lib/sonar-scanner/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
>   INFO: Project root configuration file: /home/projects/test/sonar-project.properties
>   INFO: SonarQube Scanner 4.2.0.1873
>   INFO: Java 11.0.3 AdoptOpenJDK (64-bit)
>   INFO: Linux 4.9.184-linuxkit amd64
>   INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
>   INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   INFO: Total time: 0.364s
>   INFO: Final Memory: 2M/10M
>   INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create user cache: /home/.sonar/cache
>                 at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.cache.FileCache.createDir(FileCache.java:147)
>                 at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.cache.FileCache.(FileCache.java:46)
>                 at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.cache.FileCache.create(FileCache.java:52)
>                 at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.cache.FileCacheBuilder.build(FileCacheBuilder.java:48)
>                 at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloaderFactory.create(JarDownloaderFactory.java:42)
>                 at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:68)
>                 at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart(EmbeddedScanner.java:185)
>                 at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start(EmbeddedScanner.java:123)
>                 at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:73)
>                 at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
>   Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/.sonar/cache
>                 at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
>                 at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
>                 at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
>                 at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(Unknown Source)
>                 at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Unknown Source)
>                 at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Unknown Source)
>                 at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Unknown Source)
>                 at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.cache.FileCache.createDir(FileCache.java:145)
>           ... 9 more

Here is the dockerfile I use in a docker-compose :

```
FROM sonarqube:latest  

# Switch to root user to be able to install packages.  
USER root  

# Install packages.  
RUN apt-get update  
RUN apt-get install -y vim wget  

# Install sonarqube scanner.  
WORKDIR /usr/src  

RUN wget https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-cli-4.2.0.1873-linux.zip  

RUN unzip sonar-scanner-cli-4.2.0.1873-linux.zip  
RUN rm sonar-scanner-cli-4.2.0.1873-linux.zip  
RUN mv sonar-scanner-4.2.0.1873-linux /usr/lib/sonar-scanner  

# Create symbolic link.  
RUN ln -s /usr/lib/sonar-scanner/bin/sonar-scanner /usr/local/bin/sonar-scanner  
ENV SONAR_RUNNER_HOME=/usr/lib/sonar-scanner  

ENV SONAR_USER_HOME=/home/.sonar  

# Switch back to the sonarqube environment.  
WORKDIR $SONARQUBE_HOME  
USER sonarqube
```

The docker-compose :

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    sonarqube:
        build: .
        container_name: sonarqube
        ports:
            - 9000:9000
        networks:
            - sonarnet
        environment:
            - sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonar
        volumes:
            - ./projects:/home/projects
            - sonarqube_conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf
            - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data
            - sonarqube_logs:/opt/sonarqube/logs
            - sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions

    db:
        image: postgres:latest
        container_name: sonarqube_database
        networks:
            - sonarnet
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=sonar
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sonar
        volumes:
            - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
            - postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

networks:
    sonarnet:
        driver: bridge

volumes:
    projects:
    sonarqube_conf:
    sonarqube_data:
    sonarqube_logs:
    sonarqube_extensions:
    postgresql:
    postgresql_data:
```

I understand that's an access problem, but I don't understand why.
Any ideas why is that happen ?

Comment: I see you have exported value of : `SONAR_USER_HOME`. Does retaining with bashrc helps?


`RUN echo "export SONAR_USER_HOME=/home/.sonar" >> ~/.bashrc


RUN . ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my problem. In dockerfile :

```
RUN mkdir /home/.sonar
RUN chmod 777 /home/.sonar
ENV SONAR_USER_HOME=/home/.sonar
```

Comment: For current/sonarqube user all rwx permission & for group, others just read permission may suffice with `RUN chmod -R 744 /home/.sonar`